# EF two interfering contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is not a how-to question, but rather a why&how it works. Here's the thing, when one has in his `assembly` two `namespaces` with two `contexts` implementing different parts of `TPT` tree but sharing the base tables, adding new entity fails when calling the `SaveChanges()` on the context with `UpdateException: Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details.` being thrown. The inner exception states that

> (41,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   41, 47:EntityTypes app.a.ChildB,
>   app.a.ChildA are being mapped to the same
>   rows in table xBase. Mapping conditions can be used to
>   distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

The first question what these line numbers are, where are they refer to?
Now, given the code:

```
namespace app
{
  public abstract class xBase
  {
    //...
  }
}
namespace app.a
{
  public class ChildA : xBase
  {
    //...
  }
  public class AContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<xBase>  Base     { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildA> Children { get; set; }

    public AContext()
        : base("name=AppAContext")
    {
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
  }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("PlayGround");
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new xBaseConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChildAConfiguration());
  }
  public class xBaseConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<xBase>
  {
    public xBaseConfiguration()
    {
      //...
      this.Map(m => {
               m.ToTable("xBase");
             });
    }
  }
  public class ChildAConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChildA>
  {
    public ChildAConfiguration ()
    {
      //...
      this.Map(m => {
               m.ToTable("AChildren");
             });
      }
    }
  }
}
namespace app.b
{
  public class ChildB : xBase
  {
    //...
  }
  public class BContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<xBase>  Base     { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildB> Children { get; set; }

    public BContext()
        : base("name=AppBContext")
    {
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
  }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("PlayGround");
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new xBaseConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChildBConfiguration());
  }
  public class xBaseConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<xBase>
  {
    public xBaseConfiguration()
    {
      //...
      this.Map(m => {
               m.ToTable("xBase");
             });
    }
  }
  public class ChildBConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChildB>
  {
    public ChildBConfiguration()
    {
      //...
      this.Map(m => {
               m.ToTable("BChildren");
             });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

N.B.:Both contexts use different names but point to the very same db instance.
Then when one tries to add, f.e. a new `ChildA` the aforementioned exception is thrown, like in this example:

```
using (var db = new AContext())
{
  var child = new AChild();
  //...
  db.Children.Add(child);
  db.SaveChanges(); //<--At this point the exception is thrown
}
```

In case one excludes from the assembly either of the parts of the tree, the code that operates with the second part works as desired.
Now, it can be related to this behavior or not, but for some reason, as we can see in the exception's message, the framework thinks that both parts of the hierarchy reside in the same namespace, which is not the case, originally they were, so I started with separating them, but nothing has changed, then I separated the connection strings used by two contexts, but still got same behavior. It worth mentioning that the exception is being thrown even if only one of the contexts is instantiated and as soon as the first child is inserted and `SaveChanges()` is called. So how and why one context is aware of the existence of other entities in another namespace?

Comment: What would you expect to put into `DbSet<xBase>` though? If `xBase` is abstract, you can never create the entities.

Comment: @DavidG I would not, it's used to query not to create new entities, for this example it can be omitted.

Comment: This may sound odd but instead of using Add() can you try attaching the object to the context and forcing the added state? eg: `db.Children.Attach(child);
db.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Added;`

Comment: @jcruz The very same exception is thrown, even the line numbers in the inner exception's message are the same.